# Why do my development websites in /var/www not load?

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, apache2, hosts

I configured an apache2 server on a virtualbox with ubuntu. This always worked but since yesterday my websites suddenly won't load annymore. I think it has something to do with our new network router but I'm not sure since it worked the first weeks. I have configured these things :

`000-default.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName hello.int
        ServerAdmin email@hotmail.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/hello.int/public
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

`/etc/apache2/apache.conf`:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

`hosts` file in Windows:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
10.0.2.15 hello.int
```

Shared map settings and network settings virtual box:

[image]
[image]

What I see when I surf to `localhost:8080`:

[image]

When I surf to `hello.int`:

```
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

When I surf to `127.0.0.1`:

```
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Comment: as you said you got a new router, it is possible that it dos not support backlooping or even like it is here in my situation the ISp itself doesnt support it.